# input autocomplete is mouse on

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input and I use mouseleave handler to trigger angular input errors, that works great - the errors will be highlighted when mouse will leave the input, but there is a problem with autocomplete list, when I focus on it the mouseleave handler trigger and I have a highlighted error on input. I dont want this behavior.

[image]

Is there any way to know (in js) if mouse is on autocomplete list or that autocomplete list is opend?

Comment: Depends on how you trigger that list. Are those HTML elements created by your app, or is this achieved by using HTML5 `datalist`? If the latter, the elements used to render it belong to the _Shadow DOM_, and as such you don’t have access to them via JS. // On a side note, are you sure triggering this on mouseleave is a good idea? Seeing error messages appear, just because I briefly “touched” an input element, even if I did not actually want to interact with it, but was only “on my way” to a different element … that sounds like rather bad UX.

Comment: The list is not created by my app and not HTML5 datalist. It is a standard browser cache for email input. I triger form error on mouseleave only if user toched the input, if he briefly “touched” an input element nofing will highlighted.

Comment: Ah, ok. Interesting that this triggers mouseleave (but I guess this is an edge case with no clearly specified behavior.) Perhaps as a workaround you could reverse the logic – trigger validation if _anything else_ but the currently active field is entered with the mouse cursor …?

Comment: @CBroe I didnt understend you well. The standart input mouseleave event trigers my code what checks if user had interacted with input and trigers errors if had. Ther are no any no clearly specified behavior.

Comment: I meant that this autocomplete list is rendered by the browser, it does not constitute actual HTML elements that are part of your page – and therefor it is likely not specifically defined anywhere, whether or not mouseleave should fire when you move from the input element onto that list.

Comment: You are right. But i dont nead an mouseleave event on autocomplete list. I just nead to check if mouse is on autocomplete list or autocomplete list is opend (in my mouseleave event on input).

Comment: _“I just nead to check if mouse is on autocomplete list or autocomplete list is opend”_ – again, I doubt that this is possible, because you’re dealing with a UI element here that is rendered outside of what you have in your HTML & CSS … therefor my idea that checking for mouseenter of _any other_ element might be a possible workaround.

Comment: You're right , I'm also not entirely sure that this is possible , let's see who can confirm or deny this. `therefor my idea that checking for mouseenter of any other element might be a possible workaround` - That alredy done by angular, when user clicks someweare out of the input the errors are trigerd.

Comment: _“That alredy done by angular, when user clicks someweare out of the input”_ – yeah, but I meant `mouseenter`/`mouseover` over another element, without a click – to come close to what you initially wanted to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a way to do that exactly without searching around, but I would recommend using 'focus' and 'blur' instead of mouse leave for this case.

It will not just get around this issue but will also not be restricting your functionality to mouse events as touch devices, screen readers etc do not have them.

[Angular ngBlur docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)

[Angular ngFocus docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus)

Comment: That isn't it. ngBlur and ngFocus trigers only on mouseclick (see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/deathhell/UTn5y/2/))

Answer (score 0):

Try `<input autocomplete="off">` (and here's an [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete) for your reference).

Comment: Of course it wil help, I thought about it from the start. But this removes the problem but does not solve it.

Comment: Why is this not a solution? Or do I misunderstand the real problem?

Comment: Taking away parts of the UI the user expects is hardly ever a good idea. Especially since we’re dealing with (amongst others) a field to enter an email address here – chances of me making a typo when having to type in my full email address are significantly higher, than when I would be able to just pick the email address I have used multiple times before from the autocomplete list.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I had hard time understanding the real flow of events in the question, hence the confusion.